# Formatted chararray from datetime object

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a simple way or method to take a datetime obj and get a formatted chararray object from it. 
In SQL you could use

```
to_char(myDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as myDateString
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need any further help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

[ToString](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string) converts the DateTime object to the ISO or the customized string.